# Flutter table_calendar

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if there is any way possible to make a time slot page pop out when we tap date in the table calendar.
Say for example if I click 20 in the calendar date it makes a new window pop up with the available time.

Answer (score 0):

On table_calendar package, there is a callback `onDaySelected`.  You will get the selected date as one of the parameters to the callback. You can make use of this callback and show your dialog.

```
 onDaySelected: (date, events) {
        showAlert(date);
 },
```